# std::vector<std::string> to char* array

Tags: c++, c, stl, stdvector

I have a `std::vector<std::string>` that I need to use for a `C` function's argument that reads `char* foo`.  I have [seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347949/convert-stdstring-to-const-char-or-char) [how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620329/convert-stdstring-to-char-alternative) to convert a `std::string` to `char*`.  As a newcomer to `C++`, I'm trying to piece together how to perform this conversion on each element of the vector and produce the `char*` array.

I've seen several closely related SO questions, but most appear to illustrate ways to go the other direction and create `std::vector<std::string>`.

Comment: What is the exact C interface. We can do several different things depending on where the const are and how the function treats the memory during use (C functions can do nasty things like call realloc).

Comment: Model* ModelInitialize (char *fnames, int nterms)

Comment: That function accepts `char*`, not `char**` as in your question. Which is it?

Comment: char*.  Sorry for the confusion.  I was accidentally looking at a function that takes char** fnames as an argument and later calls ModelInitialize.

Comment: Why is the `fnames` argument not const? It seems strange for an initialiser to modify its argument.

Comment: There is clearly not enough information in just the function signature to determine the correct course of action. Is ownership of `fnames` transfered into `ModelInitialize`? (if so: how must it have been allocated?) Is the calling code meant to `delete`, `free` or otherwise deallocate the `Model` returned from `ModelInitialize`? (if so: how must it be deallocated?) Must `fnames` be a null-terminated string? In what ways may `fnames` be modified?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `std::transform` as:

```
std::transform(vs.begin(), vs.end(), std::back_inserter(vc), convert);
```

Which requires you to implement `convert()` as:

```
char *convert(const std::string & s)
{
   char *pc = new char[s.size()+1];
   std::strcpy(pc, s.c_str());
   return pc; 
}
```

---

Test code:

```
int main() {
       std::vector<std::string>  vs;
       vs.push_back("std::string");
       vs.push_back("std::vector<std::string>");
       vs.push_back("char*");
       vs.push_back("std::vector<char*>");
       std::vector<char*>  vc;

       std::transform(vs.begin(), vs.end(), std::back_inserter(vc), convert);   

       for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < vc.size() ; i++ )
            std::cout << vc[i] << std::endl;

       for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < vc.size() ; i++ )
            delete [] vc[i];
}
```

Output:

```
std::string
std::vector<std::string>
char*
std::vector<char*>
```

Online demo : http://ideone.com/U6QZ5

You can use `&vc[0]` wherever you need `char**`.

Note that since we're using `new` to allocate memory for each `std::string` (in `convert` function), we've to deallocate the memory at the end.  This gives you flexibility to change the vector `vs`; you can `push_back` more strings to it, delete the existing one from `vs`, and `vc` (i.e `vector<char*>` will still be valid!

But if you don't want this flexibility, then you can use this `convert` function:

```
const char *convert(const std::string & s)
{
   return s.c_str();
}
```

And you've to change `std::vector<char*>` to `std::vector<const char*>`.

Now after the transformation, if you change `vs` by inserting new strings, or by deleting the old ones from it, then all the `char*` in `vc` might become invalid. That is one important point. Another important point is that, you don't need to use `delete vc[i]` in your code anymore.

Comment: Quick question: Why is the delete [] vc portion necessary if we're using a std::vector?

Comment: @Christopher: Because we're using `new` to allocate memory for `char*`, that is why we're doing `delete vc[i]`. But we're not allocating memory for `char**`, hence we're not doing `delete vc`.

Comment: This code leaks if the new in `convert` throws. It would be much better to use a `std::vector<char>`.

Comment: @Christopher: See my answer. Now it has more explanation.

Comment: @Mankarse: `std::vector<char>` where? In convert function? Local variable?

Comment: The convert function should return a `std::vector<char>` rather than a `char*`. If a `char*` is required later then `&vc[0]` can be used. If it is really necessary to be able to produce a `char**` then a separate vector that does not own the underlying memory should be used. If ownership of the `char*` must be moved into the C code then an RAII container should be used that automatically allocates and deallocates the `char*` appropriately, and the `char*` should be released from that container only when the ownership is transfered.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there anyway I can convert the vector<string> to char* so I can copy it elsewhere? In your approach, it looks like vc.size() is 4 but the strings have a varying length. In that case, how I convert the char** to a char*? Should I remember the individual string lengths elsewhere?

Comment: @Legend: `vs.size()` has *nothing* to do with the length of the individual strings `vs` contains. Also, read about null-terminated strings. Note that a *valid c-string* has to be null-terminated which helps you compute the length of any *c-string*.

Answer (score 11):

The best you can do is allocate an `std::vector` of `const char*` the same size as your vector. Then, walk each element of the vector, calling `c_str()` to get the string array and storing it the corresponding element of the array. Then you can pass the pointer to the first element of this vector to the function in question.

The code would look like this:

```
std::vector<const char *> cStrArray;
cStrArray.reserve(origVector.size());
for(int index = 0; index < origVector.size(); ++index)
{
  cStrArray.push_back(origVector[index].c_str());
}

//NO RESIZING OF origVector!!!!

SomeCFunction(&cStrArray[0], cStrArray.size());
```

Note that you *cannot* allow the original vector of strings to be resized between the time you fetch the `const char*`s from the `std::strings`, and the time you call the C-function.

Comment: Doesn't c_str() return a const char?  Will that be a problem if I just need a char*?  (I've included the exact interface in the comments.)

Comment: you could also do std::vector<const char *>cStrArray( origVector.size()+1, NULL); and then in the iterator use cStrArray[i]=origVector[i].c_str(); This can help with functs like execv(). But as the note above says, we could use more info about ModelInitialize.

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
char ** arr = new char*[vec.size()];
for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++){
    arr[i] = new char[vec[i].size() + 1];
    strcpy(arr[i], vec[i].c_str());
}
```

EDIT:

Here's how you would free these data structures assuming vec still has the correct number of elements, if your C function modifies this array somehow you may need to get the size another way.

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++){
    delete [] arr[i];
}
delete [] arr;
```

EDIT Again:

It may not be necessary to copy the strings if your C function does not modify the strings.  If you can elaborate on what your interface looks like I'm sure we could provide you with better help.

Comment: You need to show how to delete that array, particularly since it's so complicated. Don't forget to use `delete[]`.

Comment: This leaks if the `new` in the `for` throws. It would be much better to use a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

A C++0x solution, where elements of `std::string` are guaranteed to be stored contiguously:

```
std::vector<std::string> strings = /* from somewhere */;
int nterms = /* from somewhere */;

// using std::transform is a possibility depending on what you want
// to do with the result of the call
std::for_each(strings.begin(), string.end(), [nterms](std::string& s)
{ ModelInitialize(&s[0], nterms); }
```

If the function null terminates its argument, then after the call `(s.begin(), s.end())` might not be meaningful. You can post-process to fix that:

```
s = std::string(s.begin(), std::find(s.begin(), s.end(), '\0'));
```

A more elaborate version that separately copies each string into a `char[]`:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<char[]> pointer;
std::vector<pointer> args;
std::transform(strings.begin(), strings.end()
               , std::back_inserter(args)
               , [](std::string const& s) -> pointer
{
    pointer p(new char[s.size()]);
    std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), &p[0]);
    return p;
});

std::for_each(args.begin(), args.end(), [nterms](pointer& p)
{ ModelInitialize(p.get(), nterms); });
```

Answer (score -1):

const char* is also the same as char*, only different in the const_ness,  your interface method accepts both const and non-const string.

> Doesn't c_str() return a const char? Will that be a problem if I just
>   need a char*?

Yes, it returns a const string and no there should no problem

```
const char*a="something";
////whatever it is here
const char* retfunc(const char*a)
{
   char*temp=a;
   //process then return temp
}
```

Returning a local object is n't accepted by many people andthis tiny example is provided as an as-is.

Comment: This code will not compile. It is neither legal nor safe to assign a pointer-to-const to a pointer-to-non-const.

Comment: "Returning a local object isn't accepted by many people" // No, this is rubbish. Returning a _reference_ or _pointer_ to a local object isn't accepted by the language or by compilers. But this is not the same.

Comment: And not only is this code non-valid, but even if you'd _actually_ casted away the `const`ness, it would be a horrendously silly thing to do.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak for your corrections and comments, please don't be too harsh, it's another idea, how to make it safer still depends on the OP's actual coding experience...

Comment: "const char* is also the same as char*, only different in the const_ness" that is as helpful as stating that "apples are the same as oranges, just different"

Answer (score -2):

The elements of a vector are [stored contiguously](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#69), so the best and easy way is:

```
std::vector<char> v;
char* c = &v[0];
```