# How to pass a dymamic array of strings pointers from C++ to a C function

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [std::vector<std::string> to char* array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048888/stdvectorstdstring-to-char-array)

I have to call a c function that accepts an array of string pointers. Example

```
void cFunction(char* cities[], int count)
 {
   for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i )
   {
    printf("%s\n", cities[i]);
   }
 }
```

Assume that function is in some third party libabry; it cannot be changed
I can declare a static array and call the function like this

```
char* placesA[] = {"Teakettle Junction", "Assawoman Bay", "Land O' Lakes", "Ion", "Rabbit Hask" };
cFunction(placesA, 5);
```

That works. But my data is dynamic i.e. the size of the array changes many times at runtime
So I tried this

```
std::vector<std::string> placesB(placesA, placesA + 5);
cFunction(&placesB[0], 5); // this won't work because std::string != char*[]
```

Tried this

```
std::vector<char*> placesC; 
cFunction(&placesC[0], 5);
```

I find `placesC` awkward to populate at the sametime avoid memory leaks
 I am looking for a solution that is both efficient ( as little string copying as possible and preferably uses STL and or Boost )

Comment: @Bertrand Marron Not a duplicate. My source data does not have to be std::string. I used std::vector<string> as one possible intermediate step in the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's going to be some awkwardness no matter how you slice it.  If the C API truly requires modifiable arrays, then that's what you'll need to provide -- you'll have to copy your strings into.  If it doesn't modify the strings, then you can use a `std::vector` of `const char*`, where the string data is still owned by the underlying `std::string` objects; you just have to be careful that the C API doesn't hold onto references to those strings and tries to access them after the strings have been modified or deallocated.

For example, here's one way to do it:

```
// Unary functor which calls c_str() on a std::string object
struct StdStringCStrFunctor
{
    const char *operator() (const std::string& str) { return str.c_str(); }
};
...

std::vector<std::string> places;
... // populate places

// Convert to array of C strings
std::vector<const char *> placesCStr(places.size());
std::transform(places.begin(), places.end(), placesCStr.begin(), StdStringCStrFunctor());
cFunction(const_cast<char**>(&placesCStr[0]), placesCStr.size());
```

Comment: This looks neat. Let me do some tests

Comment: Just curious if there is no memory leak in here. Who deletes the char* s inside placesCStr

Answer (score 3):

You can write a function that populates a `vector<char*>` from a `vector<string>` using `.c_str()` on each string.

Comment: And then you can pass `&charvec[0]` to the `cFunction()`.

Comment: That requires a `const_cast` but with a bit of care on the callee’s site this works.

Comment: Using `&the_string[0]` won't require the `const_cast` (assuming a non-const view of the vector), but requires C++0x as C++03 doesn't make the guarantee that the elements of `std::basic_string` are contiguous in memory.